# using clmm with random factor. Output?

Tags: r, anova, ordinal

I have a data set of trees from different populations (`Pop_ID`) that I scored based on leaf senescence (`Score`) at different moments in time (`Date`). 
I want to use a mixed models for ordinal data with Gen_ID (genotype) as a random factor. I use the ordinal package.

```
fit=clmm(Score~Date*Pop_ID+ (1|Gen_ID), data=subset)
```

Here is what my data looks like:

> ```
> ID2 Gen_ID  Pop_Id    Country    Score Datum Date
> 1   2  FR213    FR2    France         2 23okt      1
> 2   4  PO148    PO2    Poland         3 23okt      1
> 3   5  FR218    FR6    France         2 23okt      1
> 4   6   NE91    NE4 The Netherlands   2 23okt      1
> 5   8   FR21    FR1    France         2 23okt      1
> 6   9    D68    DU2    Germany        2 23okt      1
> ```

I don't understand the different options that clmm uses such as link or treshold.

I am also unsure how to read the output. I would like to do an anova but I get the following error:

> Error in (function (object, ...)  :    anova is not implemented for a
>   single "clm" object

Anova(fit) also gives me an error:

> Error in vcov.clm(object, method = "Cholesky") : Cannot compute vcov: 
>   Hessian is not positive definite

I would like to use a lsmeans but I am not sure how to

```
lsmeans(fit,~Datum2,mode="linear.predictor")
```

But this gives me the following error

> Error in vcov.clm(object, method = "Cholesky") : Cannot compute vcov: 
>   Hessian is not positive definite

How can I solve this?

When would you use Hess=T in your model?

I would appreciate the help. Thank you!

Comment: It looks like you are using the ordinal package? Next time, show your code including any packages you library(). Also, include some data. If you can't share your data, make some up that is representative. After `library(ordinal)` you can type `?clmm` in the console to find out more about the parameters passed to the function. You will find explanations on link as well threshold. Scroll down to Value and you get the output of the function. In this case, a list. Most R packages have vignettes. Have you tried this one for [clmm](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ordinal/vignettes/clmm2_tuto

Comment: Thank you for the help, I have made some changes to it.

Comment: My guess is that `Gen_ID` corresponds to individual observations and hence that its random effect is completely confounded with error. If so, just use clm without the random term.

Comment: Sure, Jane. If it helped can you give my answer an up or select it as the answer? Also, I think anova requires two models - that's why it was giving you the error 'anova is not implemented for a single "clm" object'. Let us know what your solution was/is so we can all learn from it. Thanks!